# Navigation bar not displaying inside childViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have created a `hamburger menu` in my ios app.

I have a `navigationBar` in my `rootViewController` but now I need to move the `navigationBar` to one of my `childViewController` for some of the `functions/buttons` to work.

Now that I have moved it into a `childViewController` the `navigationBar` doesn't display. If I make the `childViewController` the `rootController` the `navigationBar` displays fine, this is because in my `appDelegate` I have the `rootController` as a `navigationController`.

It is only when I make it a `childViewController` that the `navigationBar` decides to not display. Not sure what I need to do for it to work.

Here is my `appDelegate` where I am making the `rootViewController`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: jobListController())


        return true
    }
```

This is my hamburger menu's `viewDidLoad` `(rootViewController)` where I am adding the `childViewControllers`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        // ADD VIEWCONTROLLERS TO MENU
        view.addSubview(sideBarUIView)

        addChildViewController(sideBar)
        view.addSubview(sideBar.view)
        sideBar.view.center = sideBarUIView.center

        addChildViewController(jobList)
        view.addSubview(jobList.view)
        jobList.view.center = overlayView.center

        // ADD UI VIEWS TO HAMBURGER MENU
        view.addSubview(overlayView)
        overlayView.isHidden = true
    }
```

This is the `childViewController` that I want to add the `navigationBar` to:

```
class jobListController: UIViewController {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)
        navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

        navigationItem.title = "JOBS"

        let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .search, target: self, action: #selector(HandleSearch))
        let addNewJobButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .compose, target: self, action: #selector(HandleNewJob))
        searchButton.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.63, green:0.63, blue:0.63, alpha:1.0)
        addNewJobButton.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.63, green:0.63, blue:0.63, alpha:1.0)

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [addNewJobButton, searchButton]
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

After using Lukáš Mareda's answer which seemed to fix the problem I was having, it created a new problem.

On my rootController (hamburger menu) I can slide right anywhere on the screen and it will open the hamburger menu, this is great as this is the desired effect.

One of my child viewControllers that is inside my hamburgerMenu has a tableView. If I click on one of the cells and go to a new viewController the hamburger menu can still be accessed by sliding right.

I only want to be able to access the hamburger menu at the top level but it seems taht I can access it anywhere on my app now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Hamburger Menu view controller should be subclass of UIViewController. And first step in appDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = HamburgerViewController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

2) HamburgerView controller should embed NavigationController (or its subclass) with some rootview controller. So in HamburgerViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        // ADD VIEWCONTROLLERS TO MENU
        view.addSubview(sideBarUIView)

        addChildViewController(sideBar)
        view.addSubview(sideBar.view)
        sideBar.view.center = sideBarUIView.center

        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: jobListController())
        addChildViewController(navigationController)
        view.addSubview(navigationController.view)
        navigationController.view.center = overlayView.center

        // ADD UI VIEWS TO HAMBURGER MENU
        view.addSubview(overlayView)
        overlayView.isHidden = true
    }
```

3) JobList can stay at it is. I assume that in current state, the `navigationController` property was nil

**Updated answer**

There is two ideas about handling your `hamburgerGestureRecognizer`

1) You can add the hamburgerGestureRecognizer into `rootViewController`.view
in your case it was `JobList` so the gesture recognizer will be only in rootViewController

```
            let jobList = jobListController()
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: jobList)
            addChildViewController(navigationController)
            view.addSubview(navigationController.view)
            joblist.view.addGestureRecognizer(hamburgerGestureRecognizer)
            navigationController.view.center = overlayView.center
```

And at place where you switching between screens in hamburgerMenu you can reuse this recognizer

```
viewControllerToPresent.view.addGestureRecognizer(hamburgerGestureRecognizer)
```

2) You can implement the gesture recognizer's delegate function and conditionally disable it according presenting viewController. Something like this:

```
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return currentlyPresentedNavigationController.viewControllers.count == 1
    }
```

Comment: I have just realized that this makes the hamburger work anywhere in my app, not just at the root level. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please describe it more. There is usually two way how to open hamburger menu - menu button often placed at left position in navigation bar. And the gesture from left edge (in case of left side menu). In menu button case. You should provide leftButtonItem in any viewController where you want to use it. In case of gesture recognizer, you have to implement delegate function  gestureRecognizerShouldBegin and return true only at the level where do you want to use it.

Comment: I have added the problem to my main question, under **Edit**

Answer (score 0):

You need to push VC. Set the root to your hamburgerMenuVC, and...
Inside your hamburgerMenuVC do:

```
let jobListVC = self.navigationController?.childViewController[0] as! jobListController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(jobListVC, animated: true)
```

Or:

```
let jobListVC = jobListController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(jobListVC, animated: true)
```

Or:

```
let vcs = [jobListController()]
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(vcs, animated: true)
```

Add the views inside jobListController, not hamburgerMenuVC (create CGRect etc.)

Comment: The code fails on the first line with this error: **Could not cast value of type 'App.homeMenu' (0x102822420) to 'App.jobListController' (0x102821988).** Is there a way I can just make the jobListController a navigation bar instead?

Comment: Check the edit - try second option, or... Try adding new nav:
`let 2navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: jobListController())
self.present(2navVC, animated:true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Oh excuse me, no "2' in the name. How did that go.

Comment: That partly works, it does push to jobListController which is great, but then I am stuck on adding the views to the jobListController as all the gestures that control the hamburgerMenu are in my hamburgerMenuVC

Comment: Oh yes, as we created a new nav. To me, the second option from my answer should work just fine? Actual navigationController with root of hamburgerMenuVC pushes to another VC - jobListVC - which should have declared view in storyboard, or in another file e.g. jobList.swift - in jobListVC viewDidLoad - view = jobList()

Comment: Thanks for the help but @Lukáš Mareda gave me a more straight forward answer